# JS hiding a div, while showing another

Tags: javascript, hide, mouseover

So I've looked at other questions and while they've been helpful I'm still horribly stuck. My lack of JS/jquery skills are not helping. (It might be a stupid question but I won't learn if I don't ask)

I'm working in CF environment and, basically, I've got a page. When a user hovers over a div block a large div block comes up to cover this original div. Then when the user clicks a close link the page reverts to its previous state.

So right now I have :

```
<div onmouseover="getStuff();" style="position:absolute;left:150px;top:255px;width:240px; border:1px solid blue;">
    <div class="title"><b>Title</b><br /><br />Aenean magna sem, fringilla id malesuada nec, facilisis id quam.  </div>
</div>
```

Which activates:

```
    <script>
    var iAlreadyGotStuff = 0;
    function getStuff() {
        if (!iAlreadyGotStuff) {
            gsSimpleAjax({url:'ajax.cfm?mode=content', target:'myTarget'});
            iAlreadyGotStuff = 1;
        }
    }

</script>
```

the ajax.cfm basically just pulls in a table that fits over the main page of the page.

Example: http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/8548/exampleyt.png

What JS code do I need to use or changes to I need to make to Hide the Div class "title" what the div class "myTarget" my Target is active.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
document.getElementById('title').style.display='none'
```

Comment: [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) != [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.getElementsByClassName)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an ID to the class and it should work

```
 <div class="title" id="title"><b>Title
```

Edit:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: Glad it worked for you, if you've got a moment you might consider accepting one of the proposed answers. (It'll help both of you out!)

Comment: Done and Done,  I am having a slightly different issue now. I have two divs that I want to hide like above. I use the same id and class for both divs but only one is hiding. any last minute advice?

Comment: ID's need to be unique. Switch to class names and use document.getElementsByClassName - http://jsfiddle.net/WpdqC/

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for me. I have 2 divs. I need them both to hide when an include is pulled into the page. They both have the class name "kudos". When I give one an ID and use the getElementByID it hides but not the other (only one hides) but neither hide when I use getElementsByClassName

Comment: Code:
'<div onmouseover="gsSimpleAjax({url:'kudos.cfm?mode=content', target:'myTarget'});document.getElementsByClassName('kudos').style.display='none';" style="border: 2px solid blue">   <div class="kudos"><h2>Kudos</h2>    </div></div>'

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns an array, so you'll need to iterate over the array and set each element to display='none'. Check the jsFiddle in my other comment for an example with the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Nitpick: Get away from 0 and 1, use true and false. `var iAlreadyGotStuff = false;`.

To your question, check out this script from http://webdesign.about.com/od/dhtml/a/aa101507.htm

`<script type="text/javascript">
function unhide(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
        item.className=(item.className=='hidden')?'unhidden':'hidden';
    }
}
</script>`

If the DIV is hidden, it's shown. If it's visible, it's hidden. There's a more thorough explanation at the link.

Comment: The 0 and 1 was given via another designer. I've switched it out for true and false, thanks. Thanks for the link/help!